# Not able to get links of all the total pages

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to type `selenium` in google and get all the title text of result in a notepad file. i want to get all available links on all the pages, till last page of search. but only 1st page's link i am getting. when i debug and run, it is working for some 10 pages.help me in this.

JAVA code:

```
public class weblink 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\disha.shah/myWork/eclipse/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");
    driver.findElement(By.id("_fZl")).click();

    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new File(("E:\\disha1.txt")));
    do
     {
        List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a"));  
        for (WebElement webElement : findElements)      
        {
            System.out.println("-" + webElement.getText()); // for title
          //System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("href")); // for links
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.setOut(ps); 
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }   

        Thread.sleep(1000);


        if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Next")).isDisplayed()== true)
        { 
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Next")).click();     
        }
        else
        {   
            System.out.println("All Link is Covered");
        }


    }
    while(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Next")).isDisplayed() );
    {
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
    }


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some correction. the updated code is below.-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Application/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");
    driver.findElement(By.id("_fZl")).click();
    Boolean nextButtonFlag = true;
    // Create two separate file storing the result
    PrintStream searchTitle = new PrintStream(new File(("D:\\Titles.txt")));
    PrintStream searchLink = new PrintStream(new File(("D:\\Links.txt")));
    do
     {
               List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"));  
               for (WebElement element : findElements)
               {
                   // Write all received links and title inn txt file
                   searchTitle.append(element.getText()+"\n");
                   searchLink.append(element.getAttribute("href")+"\n");
               }   
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
               try
               {
                   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Next")).click();
                }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   //  no more next button to navigate further link
                   nextButtonFlag=false;
               }

               Thread.sleep(2500);
        }
        while(nextButtonFlag);

          System.out.println("Execution done");
          searchTitle.close();
          searchLink.close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have try this issue on my end, now it's working fine for me.

Comment: its working, but output is printed not in new line.. it prints on same line.

Comment: may i know more about nextButtonFlag ?

Comment: @disha, nextButtonFlag is used to check that next button is there for more link  and passed it in while loop. the loop iterate until there is next button. in catch `nextButtonFlag=false;` set the flag value false if there is no next button  and in `while(nextButtonFlag)` it  found `while(false)` and break the loop

Comment: i need to print page number in the result. can you help me with that?

Comment: @disha, sure . just add `searchTitle.append("======== Page no "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='cur']")).getText()+"============\n");`  before `for loop`