# List's index skipped while looping through WebElements found via findElements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've had an assignment to navigate to Google, perform search, and get the titles of all the results in the first result page.

I've used `findElements` with xpath and tried to loop through each result and                 `driver.navigate().back()`. It threw `StaleElementReferenceException` and I wrote a try-catch block and started to initialize the `findElements` in the catch block.

While trying to get the size() of my findElements, it was being determined as 9 when I used an implicit wait. Used an explicit one and also Thread.sleep and size() was indeed set to 13 - which is what I was expecting.

When all is going fine, I can see the index being skipped after 6 to 12. I could not figure out what's up. Can someone tell me where am going wrong? Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
 @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        driver = LoadWebDriver.getWebDriver();
    }
    
    @Test(priority=0)
    public void navigateTo() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    }
    
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void getTheTitles() throws InterruptedException {
        
        String xPath = "//h3/a";
        int a = 0;
        boolean loopThru = true;
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Java",Keys.ENTER);
//        WebDriverWait wait =  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
//        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xPath)));
//        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> dan = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath));
        System.out.println("** The size is "+dan.size()+" **");
        while(loopThru) {
            try {
                dan = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath));
                for (int i = a; i < dan.size(); i++) {
                    if(i==dan.size()-1){
                        loopThru=false;
                    }
                    dan.get(a).click();
                    String theTitle = driver.getTitle();
                    System.out.println(a+" "+theTitle);
                    driver.navigate().back();
                }
                
            }
            
            catch(Exception e) {
                a++;
                dan = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath));
                loopThru = true;
                    
            }
        }
    }

    
    
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
    
               driver.close();
    }
```

Comment: Look into this answer probably help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999207/not-able-to-get-links-of-all-the-total-pages/42001030#42001030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted, navigating away from the search results page by clicking on one of the links makes it impossible to use the `WebElement` references of that particular page again later. So when you go back to the search results page, you'll have to `find` the links again to be able to click on them.

Here's how I would do that (roughly based on your initial code):

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Java" + Keys.ENTER);

int size = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//h3/a"))).size();

System.out.println(size + " links");

for (int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++) {
    List<WebElement> links = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//h3/a")));

    WebElement link = links.get(idx);
    String href = link.getAttribute("href");

    link.click();

    System.out.println(idx + ": " + href + ": " + driver.getTitle());

    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Which would give you the following output:

```
12 links
0: https://java.com/de/download/: Download der kostenlosen Java-Software
1: https://www.java.com/de/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml: Welche Java-Version soll für eine 64-Bit-Version des Windows-Betriebssystems heruntergeladen werden?
2: https://www.java.com/de/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml: Warum sollte ich ältere Java-Versionen aus dem System deinstallieren?
3: https://www.java.com/de/download/help/download_options.xml: Wie installiere ich Java?
4: https://www.java.com/de/download/faq/whatis_java.xml: Was ist Java und warum brauche ich Java?
5: https://www.java.com/de/: java.com: Java + Sie
6: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java: Java – Wikipedia
7: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-Technologie: Java-Technologie – Wikipedia
8: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-Laufzeitumgebung: Java-Laufzeitumgebung – Wikipedia
9: https://www.oracle.com/de/java/: Java Software | Oracle Deutschland
10: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java: Newest 'java' Questions - Stack Overflow
11: http://www.javacafe.at/: JAVA Premiumcafe - Ein Zeichen gehobener Gastlichkeit
```

Note a couple of things aoub that solution:

1. Using explicit wait statements rather than implicit wait usually gives more predictable results as you have better control over what *exactly* you want the browser to wait for
2. Having to re-find the elements every we go back to the search results page is not ideal, but that's the simplest way to avoid the *stale element problem*. A more elegant solution would have been to find all the links first, store their `href`s and navigate to the pages separately later to retrieve the page titles.
3. Because we have to find the elements again every time after we navigate back, we also have to apply the explicitly waiting for all links to be visible again. Without that, we would get pretty random results.

Comment: I did think of the links thing but the StaleReference thing took me elsewhere. Thanks for this. :)